# Counter of symbols

Tags: c

Why my counter of symbols is wrong?

I have a function, where `student_list[i] = "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз"` and `wchar_t test[15] = "знзнз"`, but `counter_debt` is equal 0.

```
void debt() {
  char name[100];
  wchar_t test[15];
  wchar_t * pch;
  int group;
  int exam;
  int counter_debt;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    counter_debt = 0;
    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d %S", &group, name, &exam, test);

    pch = wcschr(test, L'н');
    while (pch != NULL) {
      counter_debt++;
      pch = wcschr(pch + 1, L'н');
    }

    printf("%d %s: %d\n", group, name, counter_debt);
  }
}
```

When I made a simple function, `counter_debt` is equal 2. It's right answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main () {
  wchar_t str[] = L"знзнз";
  wchar_t * pch;
  int count = 0;

  pch = wcschr(str, L'н');
  while (pch != NULL) {
    count++;
    pch = wcschr(pch + 1, L'н');
  }
  printf("%i", count);
  return 0;
}
```

---

UPD:

```
char *student_list[1000] = [
  "4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445 ззззз", 
  "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз", 
  "4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433 знзнн", 
  "4272 Козлов И. И. 4443 ззззн"
]
```

I still have 2 functions with `char *student_list`.

I use Mac OS X 10.10.1 and Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)

Full program here: https://gist.github.com/lgl/4beee20f8d9a5662fef1

students.txt here: https://gist.github.com/lgl/ebd21d29700284feea11

Comment: IMO this line is wrong `sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d %S", &group, name, &exam, test);` Show us what is `student_list`?

Comment: @Gopi `char *student_list[1000] = ["4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445 ззззз", "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз", "4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433 знзнн", "4272 Козлов И. И. 4443 ззззн"]`

Comment: Propably a typo, but this `char *student_list[1000] = [ ...` isn't C.

Comment: @alk sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Initialisers go into curly brackets: `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what data format is used to store characters in `student_list`:

- if it is already `wchar_t`, You should use `swscanf()`;
- if it is UTF-8, You should convert `test` to `wchar_t` via `mbstowcs()` before using wide char functions on it.

UPD (as in Your example):

`student_list` should have `wchar_t`, not `char`.

To make `mbstowcs()` work (this function depends on locale), You need to call:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Comment: I still have 2 functions with `char *student_list`

Comment: @pertpoert, then check what is realy stored in `student_list` via debuger. It may be some cyrylic encoding, UTF-8 or some garbage (because of lost data). Please clarify what OS and compiler are You using?

Comment: I use Mac OS X 10.10.1 and Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)

Comment: @pertpoert what encoding is used to store `students.txt`? If unknown - please show hexdump of `students.txt`.

Comment: `file -bi students.txt --> regular file`, `file --mime students.txt
students.txt: ERROR: line 22: regexec error 17, (illegal byte sequence); charset=utf-8`. student file here: https://gist.github.com/lgl/ebd21d29700284feea11

Answer (score 1):

Use swscanf instead of sscanf l. Is the same function, but it accepts wide chars.